# Is there any way I can execute my node js and puppeteer program with an exe file?

Tags: node.js, netbeans, cmd, exe, puppeteer

This program works well on puppeteer when i use it on CMD. Although, it is a lengthy process and also complicated for any non-technical person. I want to make an exe file that perform the task I do manually to run this node.js file in CMD. As you can see first my program will open the browser and goto a (URL). I want to make different program with different URL. So that, if a person want to run this code, he just click the exe file and then that software will automatically do that task for the user.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function getPic() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setViewport({width: 2576, height: 4134})
  await page.goto('http://absoluteindianews.com/epaper- 
  en/index.php/epaper/edition/906/delhi-edition');
for (let i=1; i<=8; i++){
  await page.click('#page_area > a > img');
  await page.waitFor(4000);

  await page.screenshot({path: 'C:/Users/biznis/Desktop/automatic 
  downloading/Puppeteer/AbsoluteIndia/Delhi/Delhi'+ i +'.png'});

  await page.waitFor(2000);
  await page.click('#cboxLoadedContent > img');

  await page.waitFor(2000);
if(i<8) {
  await page.click('#yw1 > li.next > a');
}
  await page.waitFor(2000);
};

  await page.setViewport({width: 2576, height: 4134})
  await page.goto('http://absoluteindianews.com/epaper- 
  en/index.php/epaper/edition/905/mumbai-edition');
for (let i=1; i<=8; i++){
  await page.click('#page_area > a > img');
  await page.waitFor(4000);

  await page.screenshot({path: 'C:/Users/biznis/Desktop/automatic 
  downloading/Puppeteer/AbsoluteIndia/Mumbai/Mumbai'+ i +'.png'});
  await page.waitFor(2000);
  await page.click('#cboxLoadedContent > img');

  await page.waitFor(2000);
if(i<8) {
  await page.click('#yw1 > li.next > a');
}
  await page.waitFor(2000);
};

  await page.setViewport({width: 2576, height: 4134})
  await page.goto('http://absoluteindianews.com/epaper- 
  en/index.php/epaper/edition/904/bhopal-absolute');
for (let i=1; i<=8; i++){
  await page.click('#page_area > a > img');
  await page.waitFor(4000);

  await page.screenshot({path: 'C:/Users/biznis/Desktop/automatic 
  downloading/Puppeteer/AbsoluteIndia/Bhopal/Bhopal'+ i +'.png'});
  await page.waitFor(2000);
  await page.click('#cboxLoadedContent > img');

  await page.waitFor(2000);
if(i<8) {
  await page.click('#yw1 > li.next > a');
}
  await page.waitFor(2000);
};

  await browser.close();
}

getPic();
```

Comment: Is a batch file also okay? Then you could simply create a file with the content `node file.js` and name it to `file.bat`. Otherwise you should look into [nexe](https://github.com/nexe/nexe).

Comment: @ThomasDondorf The batch file won't work if the machine executing the exe doesn't have puppeteer installed right?

Comment: @tchan Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple ways to resolve this and writing them into single answer is not possible. However I can provide some guideline above `nexe` and `electron`. There are also `enclosejs` and `pkg` as well.

In both solution below, one of the most important rule is not to bundle your node_modules folder. Chromium binary will not work if you bundle it.

## Nexe

You can use [nexe](https://github.com/nexe/nexe). Which will download and bundle your nodejs script into a single executable file. Install it globally,

```
npm i -g nexe
```

Then create your puppeteer script. here is a sample file,

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

async function scraper(url) {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(url);
  const title = await page.title();
  await browser.close();
  return title;
}

scraper("http://example.com").then(console.log);
```

Now bundle it using,

```
nexe index.js
```

Finally copy the **node_modules folder** and the **bundled executable** file to your client.

## Electron

You can have a nice GUI with electron and create a executable file using electron-builder.

*PS: The GUI is optional, and not part of this answer. It's just to show how you can have executable file for your client which can do much more than just run the browser.*

I won't go into what is electron and how it works, instead I'll use a quickstart example. If you want to have final code, [check this repo](https://github.com/entrptaher/electron-quickstart-puppeteer).

First clone the quick start repo,

```
git clone https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start
```

Then install puppeteer and electron-builder,

```
yarn add puppeteer
npm i -g electron-builder
```

Now edit the `main.js` and add `nodeIntegration: true` to `webPreferences`,

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
      nodeIntegration: true // <-- this line
    }
})
```

Now edit `index.html` and add a button and result container,

```
<p><button>Get Result</button><div id="result"></div></p>
```

Edit `renderer.js` and paste the sample code we used on nexe example. Additionally use these lines,

```
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", async function() {
  const result = await scraper("http://example.com");
  document.querySelector("#result").innerHTML = result;
});
```

Now open package.json and add these options so we can run the chromium binary file,

```
"build": {
    "extraResources": "node_modules",
    "files": [
      "!node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Now build the app,

```
electron-builder
```

Open `dist` folder and you will get your packages apps. You can run and get the result,

[image]

Comment: I am glad it worked although when i run it on my client's pc it says that the version of the window is not compatible with the program and i complied this on windows 10 and my client have windows 7. Does that make any difference and if yes what can be done to solve this issue? Also, one more question that do i need to install puppetter and node.js in my client's pc also..!!

Comment: 1. Maybe your client has 32bit while you packaged for 64bit. You need to build/package for 32 bit in that case. 2. You need to copy the node_modules folder properly. It will have puppeteer. The build file have nodeJS packaged with it.

Comment: I am sure you must have familiar with node.js and puppeteer. await page.screenshot({path: 'C:/Users/biznis/Desktop/automatic 
  downloading/Puppeteer/AbsoluteIndia/Delhi/Delhi'+ i +'.png'});
This command save the screenshot to my local drive where else this location doesn't exist in my client's system. Is their any way i can create the directory like (cd C:/Users/biznis/Desktop/automaticdownloading/Puppeteer/AbsoluteIndia/Delhi) so that my client doesn't need to make the same directrooy manually..!

Comment: For situations like this, you can save on a relative path. If there a reason why the screenshot must be saved on that specific path?

Comment: We are going to take screen shot on daily basis of the e-papers. For that, i am going to use date() function to create the path as if today is 05/07/2019 so my screenshot must be saved in \\localdisk:D\\epapername\\2019\\07\\05 and if i run this exe file tomorrow the it should automatically save the screenshot in \\localdisk:D\\epapername\\2019\\07\\06 and for this i need something which must create the directory automatically as there are hundreds of epaper and not possible for me to make directory manually daily.

Comment: You should create another question.

Comment: According to GitHub question you have to set ExecutablePath to Chromium, please ref https://dev.to/sonyarianto/practical-puppeteer-playing-with-puppeteer-core-7i0

Comment: hello i followed your example and when i click on the 'Get Result' button it cause an error in the console it says 
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Passed function is not well-serializable!
does any one know why am getting this issue ?

Comment: guys any help ?

Comment: What is the electron and node version? Maybe this should be a chat instead of a long discussion/comments thread.