# How to create graphic interface for a node js puppeteer app?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

What's the best and the easiest way to create a modern graphic interface for a node js puppeteer app ?

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add a UI to a node+puppeteer app and the best explanation of how to get node.js, puppeteer and an electron based UI  to play together is given here [Is there any way I can execute my node js and puppeteer program with an exe file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56810069).

This answer in turn links to a gitHub repository https://github.com/entrptaher/electron-quickstart-puppeteer.

Although it answers this I didn't mark your question as a duplicate of 56810069 as it was difficult to find. Full marks to original author for a spot on explanation

I built my GUI with Electron, Vue and Vuetify but your mileage may vary. Works well